# Exibir resultados rezados

Tags: select, join, count

Boa noite estou criando um sistema de indicação,
Mas o resultado da query não retorna os usuários com indicações zero

Aqui está meu select

```
  SELECT 
   c.id, 
   c.nome, 
   funcao, 
   area, 
   count(p.cpf_cli) AS quantidade 
FROM col c 
LEFT JOIN indicacao p 
   ON p.id_colaborador = c.id 
WHERE 
   indicacao.data_ind BETWEEN `2018/09/20` AND '2018/09/21'
GROUP BY 
   c.id, c.nome 
ORDER BY
   c.nome
```

Comment: qual banco, mysql?

Comment: aliás, as colunas funcao e area deveria estar no `group by`, senão vai dar erro no seu select

Comment: O banco é o MySQL,  está funcionando, porém os colaboradores que não indicarão não retorna na consulta

Comment: Exemplo: anderson 0 indicações, maria 3 indicacoes

Comment: sem ver os dados da tabela é difícil dizer o que é, se colocar um exemplo dos dados fica mais fácil de ajudarmos

Comment: nao consigo enviar fotos,

Comment: CREATE TABLE  `col` (
  `id` int(10) NOT NULL,
  `nome` varchar(90) NOT NULL,
  `funcao` varchar(90) NOT NULL,
  `area` varchar(90) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `indicacao` (
  `nome_cli` varchar(120) NOT NULL,
  `cpf_cli` varchar(14) NOT NULL,
  `id_colaborador` int(10) NOT NULL,
  `data_ind` datetime DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
  `status` int(2) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  PRIMARY KEY (`cpf_cli`),
  KEY `id_colaborador` (`id_colaborador`)

Comment: essas sao minhas tabelas que estao relacionadas col(colaborador) e indicacao

Answer (score 0):

Olá, boa noite. Faça da seguinte forma que vai funcionar, abçs:

SELECT 
   c.id, 
   c.nome, 
   funcao, 
   area, 
   count(p.cpf_cli) AS quantidade 
FROM col c 
LEFT JOIN indicacao p 
   ON p.id_colaborador = c.id 
WHERE 
   date_format(indicacao.data_ind, "%Y%m%d") BETWEEN '20180920' AND '20180921'
GROUP BY 
   c.id, c.nome 
ORDER BY
   c.nome

Comment: nao esta funcionando